# TypeError: Cannot call method "<method>" of undefined, when defining a function, sees parameter as undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a Javascript function for a Google Script, but I keep getting the error:

`TypeError: Cannot call method "<method>" of undefined`

When I call methods on the arguments of my function. Here is the code below:

```
function rolldice(dice) {
  var d_ind = dice.indexOf('d');
  var die_num = Number(dice.substr(d_ind,0));
  var die = Number(dice.substr(d_ind + 1, dice.length()));
  var value = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < die_num; i++) {
    value += Math.floor((Math.random() * die) + 1);
  };
  return value;
};
```

It expected dice to be defined as a string already when it is the argument of the function, but that doesn't really make any sense to me.

Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Or if this error tends to crop up when using Google's Script Editor in general.

**edit:**
Some people have told me that the issue likely is that I am calling the function on something that is not a string, but currently the script is only what I have in the code block, and it does not call this function anywhere.

Yet when running the script (which shouldn't do anything other than define a function and never use it), I still get this error

**edit 2:**
It looks like running a function within Google Script Editor will cause it to be a little wonky, and it will try to run the lines of functions as if they are not in functions, and just treat arguments as undefined variables.

But it doesn't affect if the script works in a google sheet or not

Comment: Show where the function is being called. You're probably passing an undefined in, instead of a string.

Comment: Well if `dice` is `undefined` it means you didn't pass a string when calling it.

Comment: dice.length is a property not a method.  Get rid of the parentheses following it.

Comment: The script at the moment is literally what I put in the code block, I don't call it
^Thanks James, for catching that, though that didn't affect this error

Comment: If you don't expect the function to run but it runs, fix that problem first. Replace the whole function body with `console.log(dice); debugger;` please and try again

Comment: I messed around with it a bit more, and it just seems like it's an idiosyncrasy of Google's script editor, and nothing is wrong as per my edit 2